# Teams planner tab add using graph API error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

POST: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/teamsId/channels/channelId

Request body

```
{
    "displayName": "Task  management",
    "teamsApp@odata.bind" 
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/appCatalogs/teamsApps/com.microsoft.teamspace.tab.planner",
    "configuration": {
        "entityId": "",
        "contentUrl": "",
        "websiteUrl": "",
        "removeUrl": ""
    }
}
```

1. entityId = plan id
2. contentUrl = websiteUrl = removeUrl = https://tasks.office.com/{tenantName}/Home/PlannerFrame?page=7&planId={planId}

Graph API's docs referred

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-configuring-builtin-tabs
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamstab-add?view=graph-rest-beta

But works fine if created using teams app or even update the same tab using settings.

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the logs, the URL you are specifying for the contentUrl seems to be missing the "page=7" query parameter, which looks like the reason the page doesn't load.

Comment: Thanks it's working. "page=7" I thought this is a tab number and tried with other numbers and removing that number as well.

Comment: It is an indicator of which view to show. We're not really happy with how this works, but until we have a better way, missing the parameter will fail to render anything.